# twitter bootsrap modal appears on top of menu (unclickable links)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, position, z-index

I am working at this site http://www.digiruptiva.com/site/
If you scroll to "Serviços" section at the home page you will see a row of icons and a blue button with the text "saber mais". When you click in the button, a modal opens containing more information.

The problem is: Some links in the top menu like (Quem Somos and Serviços) arent clickable becuase the hidden modal is getting in the way.

I tried moved the modals before the close body tag but still the same problem. I found a topic here an S.0 saying that adding data-backdrop="false" to the modal element solves the problem but I want to have the backdrop.

How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think I solved it by adding .modal { display: none; } to my css ile.